# Display one element above another

Tags: html, css, positioning

Semantically it makes sense in the document to be written like this, I also imagine it better for SEO.

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

However, I want the 'main' section to be above the 'header' on screen.

Is there a way to do this using pure CSS?

Comment: Above as in vertically above, or above as stacked on top of?

Comment: For Semantic purpose, i would suggest you to use <header> instead of <div id="header">

Comment: Vertically above, just how they would normally appear, but with the main section appearing first on the page.

Answer (score 2):

One way is with a container and some absolute positioning.

http://jsfiddle.net/QpPh4/

```
.container
{
    position:relative;
}

#main
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:100%;
}
```

```
<br><br>
<div class="container">
   <div id="header">Hi I'm a header</div>
   <div id="main">Hi I'm the content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The main section is cut off by the top of the browser as it is absolutely positioned.

Comment: @Tom I know.  That's why I gave it a few `<br>`s.  This is just the general idea of how to position the other element directly on top of the first one.